# How to fix linter expected to return a value at the end of react function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linter

I create a function component to render error message, but its has a linter warning "Expected to return a value at the end of function 'renderErrorMessage' consistent-return

```js
function renderError() {
    if (errors.file) {
      return (
        <Grid item>
          <Grid container direction="column">
            <Grid item>
              <Text size="14px" height="1.43" isError>
                Error Data :
              </Text>
            </Grid>
            {errors.file.map((message) => (
              <Grid item key={message}>
                <Text size="12px" isError>
                  {message}
                </Text>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because there is no default return statement. `return something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function will not return any value if `errors.file` condition is false, thats why you're getting the warning. You can refactor your component like this:

```
function renderError() {
  if (!errors || !errors.file) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Grid item>
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <Text size="14px" height="1.43" isError>
            Error Data :
          </Text>
          </Grid>
          {errors.file.map((message) => (
            <Grid item key={message}>
              <Text size="12px" isError>
                {message}
              </Text>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
}
```